# Resource Plugin can not be found when it is defined in a different dll/project

Tags: c#, moryx

I tried to define a resource in a library that should be extensible via strategies.

The idea was to create a reusable resource, for which only some small pieces need to be defined
in machine specific implementations.

Unfortunately the new implementations are not loaded and can not be used in the resource manager.

For that I defined a resource conceptually like this:

```cs
// All in my library project:

// The interface for the strategy
public interface IStrategy {
    public void DoStuff();
}

// An implementation of that strategy the library
[Plugin(LifeCycle.Transient, typeof(IStrategy), Name = nameof(DefaultImplementation))]
public class DefaultImplementation : IStrategy {
    public void DoStuff() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}

// The resource that should be extended
[ResourceRegistration]
[DependencyRegistration(InstallerMode.All)]
public class DemoResource: Resource {

    [DataMember, EntrySerialize, PluginNameSelector(typeof(IStrategy))]
    public string StrategyName {get;set;}
}
```

And a new project specific implementation of this interface  in another project:

```cs
[Plugin(LifeCycle.Transient, typeof(IStrategy), Name = nameof(SpecificImplementation))]
public class SpecificImplementation : IStrategy {
    public void DoStuff() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from my specific project");
}
```

When I launch the project and create a new instance of `DemoResource` via the `ResourceManager`, I am unable to select my custom implementation.

I read the doc comment that `DependencyRegistration` only picks up implementation in my assembly, so I am not really surprised.

Does anyone know a workaround to tell `MORYX` to pickup strategies from other assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is a way in MORYX to resolve this issue. As you already stated the `DependencyRegistration` attribute by default only searches within the same assembly. However, you can provide your own `ISubInitializer` strategy to the attribute, which allows you to search for the components you need in the container.

For your example it could look similar to this implementation

```cs
public class YourSubInitializer : ISubInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(IContainer container)
    {
        container.LoadComponents<IStrategy>();
    }
}
```

and would need to be included in the attribute as follows

```cs
[DependencyRegistration(InstallerMode.All, Initializer = typeof(YourSubInitializer))]
```

Comment: If there is nothing else to add from that assembly, the installer mode should be `None`